# How can the user place a custom text string as a placeholder for a plugin

Tags: tags

ex: like a user adds {{my-new-plugin}} somewhere in their post, the plugin will read it and add arbitrary text.

I just need help finding the name for this. I can't find this the proper words to put in a search engine.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the word shortcode. Some plugins have them and some do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking or are short codes.

Check the codex for more details on them:

- [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API%20Shortcode%20API)
- [Builtin Short Codes and Overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode)

Hopefully that gets you going.

Answer (score 1):

It is:

```
wp.template( templateName )
```

I can't find it in Codex and could not explain it better, so [here's a link](https://lkwdwrd.com/wp-template-js-templates-wp/).